# Type I and Type II Topoisomerases

Tags: dna, molecular-genetics

Type I topoisomerase changes the linking number by ±1 by changing the number of **twist** present in a DNA, breaking only one strand.

Type II topoisomerase changes the linking number by ±2 by changing the **configuration of the writhe**,breaking both the strands.

Am I right?

Comment: Sannukta. You should know better than to give a question a meaningless title like this. It shouldn't be hard to think of something involving topoisomerases and linking number.

Comment: I hope this might help. http://www.pnas.org/content/99/19/12126/F1.expansion.html and http://www.pnas.org/content/99/19/12126/F1.large.jpg. (However I confess me too feel these mathematical topics extremely tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speculations are right.

Topoisomerase I changes the linking number by changing the number of twists and Topoisomerase II changes the linking the number by changing the writhe of DNA.

Confirmed by a college professor.